# Pandas - Reset CUMSUM after every cycle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, cumsum

I am planning to move to another position in my company and I asked for a typical assignment to train myself. To some point, I did it and I really understood things, but now I am stuck. I was searching, but nothing works for me yet as I also can't understand it, but I guess it should be some kind of a loop and I am getting errors whenever I use loops.

Basically, I have a huge Excel file with columns and a lot of data. It is about selling food and about customer fees, there was a mistake about charges and later it was fixed, I had to understand where exactly the balance got 0.00.

Here you can see data before I started working on it.

[Original Data, before I used the pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7gGN.png)

Later, I used the pivot table to separate rows from one column and found out about different data and questions, they may have in the future. So, here is my excel file after working on it.

[Data after working on it, with additional columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKFSO.png)

And here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df = pd.read_excel ('C:/Data.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1',
                    usecols = ['Payment', 'Money', 'Created'])

df['Created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created'])
df['Created'] = df['Created'].dt.round('min')

df = df.pivot_table(index = ['Created'],
                    columns = ['Payment']).fillna(0)

df['Money','fee'] = df['Money', 'fee'].round(2)
df['Fixed Fee'] = (-df['Money', 'food'] * 25) / 100
df['Fixed Fee'] = df['Fixed Fee'].round(2)

df['OverCharge'] = np.where(df['Money', 'fee'] != df['Fixed Fee'], df['Money', 'fee'] - df['Fixed Fee'], 0)
df['OverCharge'] = df['OverCharge'].round(1)

df['Percentage'] = df['Money','fee'] / df['Money','food'] * 100
df['Percentage'] = df['Percentage'].abs()
df['Percentage'] = df['Percentage'].round(2)

df['Charges'] = np.where(df['Percentage'].notna(), np.where(df['Percentage'] > 26, 'Overcharge - 30%', 'Fixed - 25%'), 'Null')

df['Correct'] = -df['Money', 'food'] - df['Fixed Fee']

df['Incorrect'] = -df['Money', 'food'] - df['Money', 'fee']

df['Balance'] = df['Correct'] - df['Incorrect']

df['Balance'] = np.where(df['Money', 'payout'] != 0, df['Correct'].cumsum() - df['Money', 'payout'], df['Balance'])

#df.to_excel("CarIndustry.xlsx")
print(df)
```

Output (First 20 rows):

```
                    Money                            Fixed Fee OverCharge Percentage           Charges Correct Incorrect Balance
Payment               fee  food  payout payoutReject
Created
2019-12-27 12:32:00  -6.00  20.0    0.00          0.0     -5.00       -1.0      30.00  Overcharge - 30%  -15.00    -14.00   -1.00
2019-12-27 12:58:00  -5.26  17.5    0.00          0.0     -4.38       -0.9      30.06  Overcharge - 30%  -13.12    -12.24   -0.88
2019-12-27 13:17:00  -3.46  11.5    0.00          0.0     -2.88       -0.6      30.09  Overcharge - 30%   -8.62     -8.04   -0.58
2019-12-30 04:01:00   0.00   0.0  -34.29          0.0     -0.00        0.0        NaN              Null    0.00     -0.00   -2.45
2019-12-30 13:24:00  -1.94   6.5    0.00          0.0     -1.62       -0.3      29.85  Overcharge - 30%   -4.88     -4.56   -0.32
2020-01-01 12:53:00  -6.00  20.0    0.00          0.0     -5.00       -1.0      30.00  Overcharge - 30%  -15.00    -14.00   -1.00
2020-01-01 13:06:00  -3.90  13.0    0.00          0.0     -3.25       -0.6      30.00  Overcharge - 30%   -9.75     -9.10   -0.65
2020-01-01 13:27:00  -3.46  11.5    0.00          0.0     -2.88       -0.6      30.09  Overcharge - 30%   -8.62     -8.04   -0.58
2020-01-01 13:38:00  -7.20  24.0    0.00          0.0     -6.00       -1.2      30.00  Overcharge - 30%  -18.00    -16.80   -1.20
2020-01-01 15:10:00  -2.10   7.0    0.00          0.0     -1.75       -0.4      30.00  Overcharge - 30%   -5.25     -4.90   -0.35
2020-01-01 16:31:00  -7.94  26.5    0.00          0.0     -6.62       -1.3      29.96  Overcharge - 30%  -19.88    -18.56   -1.32
2020-01-01 16:51:00  -2.40   8.0    0.00          0.0     -2.00       -0.4      30.00  Overcharge - 30%   -6.00     -5.60   -0.40
2020-01-01 17:00:00  -2.26   7.5    0.00          0.0     -1.88       -0.4      30.13  Overcharge - 30%   -5.62     -5.24   -0.38
2020-01-01 18:21:00  -8.26  27.5    0.00          0.0     -6.88       -1.4      30.04  Overcharge - 30%  -20.62    -19.24   -1.38
2020-01-03 13:24:00  -1.66   5.5    0.00          0.0     -1.38       -0.3      30.18  Overcharge - 30%   -4.12     -3.84   -0.28
2020-01-03 15:53:00  -3.30  11.0    0.00          0.0     -2.75       -0.5      30.00  Overcharge - 30%   -8.25     -7.70   -0.55
2020-01-03 17:39:00  -1.94   6.5    0.00          0.0     -1.62       -0.3      29.85  Overcharge - 30%   -4.88     -4.56   -0.32
2020-01-03 20:22:00  -3.14  10.5    0.00          0.0     -2.62       -0.5      29.90  Overcharge - 30%   -7.88     -7.36   -0.52
2020-01-03 21:18:00  -2.26   7.5    0.00          0.0     -1.88       -0.4      30.13  Overcharge - 30%   -5.62     -5.24   -0.38
2020-01-06 04:01:00   0.00   0.0 -134.75          0.0     -0.00        0.0        NaN              Null    0.00     -0.00  -46.36
```

And my results should be like:

```
                    Money                            Fixed Fee OverCharge Percentage           Charges Correct Incorrect Balance
Payment               fee  food  payout payoutReject
Created
2019-12-27 12:32:00  -6.00  20.0    0.00          0.0     -5.00       -1.0      30.00  Overcharge - 30%  -15.00    -14.00   -1.00
2019-12-27 12:58:00  -5.26  17.5    0.00          0.0     -4.38       -0.9      30.06  Overcharge - 30%  -13.12    -12.24   -0.88
2019-12-27 13:17:00  -3.46  11.5    0.00          0.0     -2.88       -0.6      30.09  Overcharge - 30%   -8.62     -8.04   -0.58
2019-12-30 04:01:00   0.00   0.0  -34.29          0.0     -0.00        0.0        NaN              Null    0.00     -0.00   -2.45
2019-12-30 13:24:00  -1.94   6.5    0.00          0.0     -1.62       -0.3      29.85  Overcharge - 30%   -4.88     -4.56   -0.32
2020-01-01 12:53:00  -6.00  20.0    0.00          0.0     -5.00       -1.0      30.00  Overcharge - 30%  -15.00    -14.00   -1.00
2020-01-01 13:06:00  -3.90  13.0    0.00          0.0     -3.25       -0.6      30.00  Overcharge - 30%   -9.75     -9.10   -0.65
2020-01-01 13:27:00  -3.46  11.5    0.00          0.0     -2.88       -0.6      30.09  Overcharge - 30%   -8.62     -8.04   -0.58
2020-01-01 13:38:00  -7.20  24.0    0.00          0.0     -6.00       -1.2      30.00  Overcharge - 30%  -18.00    -16.80   -1.20
2020-01-01 15:10:00  -2.10   7.0    0.00          0.0     -1.75       -0.4      30.00  Overcharge - 30%   -5.25     -4.90   -0.35
2020-01-01 16:31:00  -7.94  26.5    0.00          0.0     -6.62       -1.3      29.96  Overcharge - 30%  -19.88    -18.56   -1.32
2020-01-01 16:51:00  -2.40   8.0    0.00          0.0     -2.00       -0.4      30.00  Overcharge - 30%   -6.00     -5.60   -0.40
2020-01-01 17:00:00  -2.26   7.5    0.00          0.0     -1.88       -0.4      30.13  Overcharge - 30%   -5.62     -5.24   -0.38
2020-01-01 18:21:00  -8.26  27.5    0.00          0.0     -6.88       -1.4      30.04  Overcharge - 30%  -20.62    -19.24   -1.38
2020-01-03 13:24:00  -1.66   5.5    0.00          0.0     -1.38       -0.3      30.18  Overcharge - 30%   -4.12     -3.84   -0.28
2020-01-03 15:53:00  -3.30  11.0    0.00          0.0     -2.75       -0.5      30.00  Overcharge - 30%   -8.25     -7.70   -0.55
2020-01-03 17:39:00  -1.94   6.5    0.00          0.0     -1.62       -0.3      29.85  Overcharge - 30%   -4.88     -4.56   -0.32
2020-01-03 20:22:00  -3.14  10.5    0.00          0.0     -2.62       -0.5      29.90  Overcharge - 30%   -7.88     -7.36   -0.52
2020-01-03 21:18:00  -2.26   7.5    0.00          0.0     -1.88       -0.4      30.13  Overcharge - 30%   -5.62     -5.24   -0.38
2020-01-06 04:01:00   0.00   0.0 -134.75          0.0     -0.00        0.0        NaN              Null    0.00     -0.00  -12.07
```

To understand it better, just check the last lines, basically I want cumsum to calculate from the previous payout to the next payout and put this number at the end right there and continue like that, as this is just a small part of the data.

Comment: Hi There, welcome to SO, interesting question you have. It would really helpful if you could read [ask] and [mcve] essentially to get this question up to scratch you need to 1) ditch the photos and provide a sample input and expected output as text (like your code) 2) just try to explain, in logic what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, I fixed it, but anyway, now this question is dead as there are -2 votes.

Answer (score 1):

So the easiest way is to change how you calculate your balance column to do it how to you want to do it the first time.

```
df['balance'] = df.groupby((df['Correct'].shift() == '0').cumsum()).apply(lambda x: (x['Correct'] - x['Incorrect']).cumsum()).reset_index()[0]
```

So we are using cumsum on each group, where each group is defined as all the rows up to and including when the 'Correct' column value is equal to 0.

This replaces both your df['balance'] lines.

Comment: Hey thanks for the try, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It gives me this error -  indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key) and also this error - raise KeyError(key) from err.

Comment: I changed '0' to just 0 int version and it actually worked without errors, but all the values in Balance were Nan.